# how to check if a number is even or not in python

Tags: python, integer, modulo, collatz

I am attempting to make a collatz conjecture program, but I can't figure out how to check for even numbers
this is my current code for it

```
    elif (original_collatz % 2) == 0:
        new_collatz = collatz/2
```

anyone have an idea how to check

i tried it with modulo but could figure out how it works, and my program just ignores this line, whole program:
`

```
#collatz program
import time

collatz = 7
original_collatz = collatz
new_collatz = collatz

while True:
    if original_collatz % 2 == 1:
        new_collatz = (collatz * 3) + 1

    elif (original_collatz % 2) == 0:
        new_collatz = collatz/2

    collatz = new_collatz

    print(collatz)

    if collatz == 1:
        print('woo hoo')
        original_collatz += 1

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The problem isn't your parity check. The problem is `collatz/2` (and perhaps other problems). It should be `collatz//2` since you need integer division.

Comment: You never update `original_collatz` so your test always returns the same value... I think you want to replace `original_collatz` with `collatz` ; and you actually should think hard about your variables and what they're for! You only need 2, not 3.

Comment: If any of the answers provided a solution to your question, I am sure, the individual would appreciate you accepting the answer for their effort.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that "your program ignore the lines", it's that you test the parity of `original_collatz` which doesn't change.

- You need to check the parity of `collatz`
- You need to use integer division (`//`) when dividing by two or `collatz` will become a float.
- You don't really need to use `new_collatz` as an intermediate, you could just overwrite `collatz` directly.

Here is a fixed sample:

```
# collatz program
import time

collatz = 7
original_collatz = collatz
new_collatz = collatz

while True:
    if collatz % 2 == 1:
        new_collatz = (collatz * 3) + 1

    else:
        new_collatz = collatz // 2

    collatz = new_collatz

    print(collatz)

    if collatz == 1:
        print('woo hoo')
        original_collatz += 1
        collatz = original_collatz

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
import time

collatz_init = 7
collatz = collatz_init

while True:
    if collatz % 2 == 1:
        collatz = (collatz * 3) + 1
    else:
        collatz //= 2

    print(collatz)

    if collatz == 1:
        print('woo hoo')
        collatz_init += 1
        collatz = collatz_init

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Just  a reminder `if collatz % 2` is the same as `if collatz % 2 == 1` and  is more pythonic when you remember [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)